# Find a logical predicate for some given conditions

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am trying to give an example of a predicate $P(x, y)$ such that $\exists x$ $\forall y$ $P(x, y)$ and $\forall y$ $\exists x$ $P(x, y)$ have different truth values.  I am struggling to think of such a predicate.  Could I have a hint as to how to approach this problem?

Comment: How about $x = y$?

Comment: Would this work?  If I can find some $x$ such that, for all $y$, $x=y$, then surely it holds that, for all $y$, I can find an $x$ such that $x=y$.

Comment: @Regret: Simple and direct. +1. You should convert this to an answer.

Comment: @CKKOY: See my answer for a response to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $x=y$?

About your comment: If $\exists x\forall y(x=y)$, then your universe contains just one element. If your universe contains just one element, then every $P(x,y)$ is either true or false for all $x$ and $y$, and $\forall y\exists x \,P(x,y)\iff \exists x \forall y\, P(x,y)$.

Comment: By the way, I don't know all that much about logic terminology. If my choice of words grinds your gears, feel free to edit it.

Comment: @ Regret If $\exists x$ $\forall y$ $(x=y)$ (1) is a true statement, then isn't it necessarily true that $\forall y$ $\exists x$ $P(x, y)$ (2) also holds (since there is only one element in the universe)?  I am not sure if I am lacking some sort of understanding of this problem.  I want a predicate such that, if (1) is true, then (2) must be false.

Comment: @CKKOY: My point is that, for a universe with just one element, you will not be able to find a predicate such that $\exists\forall\ne\forall\exists$. If you wish to find such a predicate, your universe must contain more than one element, and then the predicate $P(x,y)\iff x=y$ will suffice. Do you understand?

Comment: Ah - I see. That is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. The formula $\exists x \,\forall y. P(x,y)$ wants a universal $x$, which works *for all* $y$, regardless of $y$'s nature. Where is in $\forall y\, \exists x. P(x,y)$ the $y$ may depend on the particular $x$ given. Now think of some problem, which depends on $y$, where the solution $x$ exists for every $y$, but differs.

Comment: Your hint seems to be identical to OP's question ("Think of an answer to your question, then you will have an answer", effectively).

Comment: The phrasing of this hint better enables me to approach the question.

Comment: This was my hope. @MPW I just wanted to rephrase the question in other words. It often helps, and I found it diffucult to give a hint without giving an answer, note that the OP explicitly asks for a hint.

Comment: I think that I have come up with an answer to the question.  Let the universe be $\{2, 4, 7, 21\}$ and let $P(x, y)$ be the statement $x|y.$  Then the truth value of $\exists x\forall y P(x, y)$ is false, and the truth value of $\forall y \exists x P(x, y)$ is true.  (Note that $2|2$ and $7|7.)$  Am I correct?